# Receive the actions of a headset in Android

Tags: android, groovy, bluetooth

I'm trying to write a music player for Android as a project for school and I try to intercept the action of my bluetooth headset (Parrot Zik 2.0 if it matters).

Here is my current code :

`AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<receiver android:name=".core.MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and in my class `MediaButtonReceiver` I wrote the following for test purposes (Groovy) :

```
public class MediaButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        def intentAction = intent.action
        if(!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) return

        def event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT) as KeyEvent
        if(event == null) return

        def action = event.action

        Log.e(this.class.toString(), "action : ${action}")
        switch(action)
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                Log.e(this.class.toString(), "Play/pause")
                abortBroadcast()
                break
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                Log.e(this.class.toString(), "Previous")
                abortBroadcast()
                break
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                Log.e(this.class.toString(), "Next")
                abortBroadcast()
                break
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                Log.e(this.class.toString(), "Volume up")
                abortBroadcast()
                break
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                Log.e(this.class.toString(), "Volume down")
                abortBroadcast()
                break
        }
    }
}
```

When using the following :

```
E/class augier.fr.phoebius.core.MediaButtonReceiver﹕ 0
E/class augier.fr.phoebius.core.MediaButtonReceiver﹕ 1
```

So it seems like I actually catch something but it looks like it only corresponds to event when a button is pressed and then released and I'm not able to match this to any particular action.

I'm probably using it wrong but, so far, I haven't been able to find a tutorial explaining how to catch media related events on internet.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
def action = event.action
```

try this instead:

```
def action = event.keyCode
```